# django use authenticated user in models

Tags: python, django-models, django-allauth

In django, I want to use the authenticated user in my models and I'm using allauth for authentication. In my model I have:

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

I know now that I have to put something in my settings.py like :

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
```

But this is not working. What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: In models.py I have now

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

and in my view I have

```
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.created_by = request.user
    instance.save()
```

You'll need to do it in the view, as the model has no idea where it is being created from.